# Simplest setup for a staging server and a production server -

Tags: node.js, git, github, server, version-control

What's the simplest way to manage a staging server vs production?

What's the point of having a staging server if you could just push changes to a different branch in production?

What's the best way to merge the staging server with production? Cron job?

Current setup is staging server which we don't use we are just pushing straight to production, but trying to improve the process

Answer (score 0):

> What's the simplest way to manage a staging server vs production?

The simplest and cheapest way is to get rid of your staging server.    Staging servers don't inherently make deploys safer, but generally developers want at least a dev environment (functionally not necessarily distinct from the idea of staging server) to host their code in a prod-like environment before they push it to prod.

> What's the point of having a staging server if you could just push changes to a different branch in production?

If you have 2 branches running in production simultaneously, that's functionally equivalent to a staging server.  Most shops prefer to have a *staging environment* not *server* so that their data tier, 3rd party integrations, etc. are completely separate between staging and prod.

Simply deploying another copy of your application in prod is deceptively dangerous because if you mess up the data tier or 3rd party integrations you can easily effect prod.

> trying to improve the process

Feature flags.  if you can enable new features or even fixes for specific users you can then roll it out to your QA team (or the devs, whomever is going to test) and then when you're happy with it, roll it out to the general user base.  This isn't inherently safer than anything else, but it has the advantage that it front loads the work of planning for multiple concurrent code paths and makes that planning more explicit.

Unfortunately there's no magic bullet for having testing (dev ,staging , whatever you want to call them) environments increase reliability.

> What's the best way to merge the staging server with production? Cron job?

For code, usually the preferred method is to "promote" the artifact you deployed to staging over to prod without rebuilding, guaranteeing the same thing is shipped.

for runtime environment, using containerization makes most of that part of the code artifact and that's the simplest way.  If you're running on a container-centric hosting like ECS Fargate or Google's docker oriented service, there's nothing else on the app side to ship.  This is what I recommend, it's straight forward and easy to reason about.  Adding virtual servers into the mix just adds an OS level to manage and there's little benefit to that.  If you can make your app serverless so it's not sitting waiting for connections but instead is invoked when connections come in, the same thing applies, no OS to manage (AWS lambda for example has serverless docker image support)

Data is generally considered the tricky bit to having test environments by those who have experience with them.  If your production data is not at all sensitive you can copy it over, but that may or may not actually work depending on what's in the data and how distributed your data ends up being.  Generally production data is sensitive enough that you don't want to expose it to dev environments, which makes it tricky to ensure the dev data is appropriate for testing features.  One common methodology for overcoming that obstacle is automating end-to-end tests via something like selenium for web broswers, and automated API tests for non-browser-centric endpoints.  This allows you to write the test along with the app to prove it's working.